# Python's Fabric to use rsync locally, is it possible?

Tags: python, fabric

Currently Fabric's 'rsync_projecct' requires a user and a host parameter to be specified.  I'having a lot of issues copying   user@127.0.0.1 because it is still asking me for the password for rsync.  I've spent hours on this and am wondering if there is just a way to use the rsync [src] [dest] without having to specify a [user] and [host]?  Or do you guys recommend something better?

The reason I like rsync over anything else is because I already have the rsync files/folders/excludes setup for that specific command.

Then again, I could just write my own rsync command right?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably look at setting up a public key and adding it to `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` but that's probably more suited to superuser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can just local() out and use rsync any way you want to.